# General reference for crowdsourcing

Tags: references, experiment-design

Crowdsourcing is a relatively new kind of experimental design which is getting more and more popular for example in natural language processing (NLP). I know about classical research methods but crowdsourcing seems to be different from, say, a usual survey in a number of ways.

So, is there some general reference on how to get started with crowdsourcing from a research point of view, something like a general introduction? I did a brief search on amazon. There were numerous hits but most of those seem to focus on business applications. Is there anything you can recommend?